# flask_apscheduler "error_message": "The list of positional arguments is longer than the target callable can handle (allowed: 0, given in args: 6)"

Tags: python, json, flask, arguments, apscheduler

need help on pass arguments to flask-apscheduler via POST json and im trying to add job and it should return and print testing2 every 2 seconds.

this is my json post using postnam:

```
{
    "id":"testing2",
    "func":"app:run",
    "args":"(testing2)",
    "trigger":"interval",
    "seconds":5
}
```

to URL :http://127.0.0.1:5000/scheduler/jobs

This is my code:

```
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from flask import Flask
from flask_apscheduler.utils import trigger_to_dict

from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

def run(id):
    print(str(id))

class Config:
    SCHEDULER_JOBSTORES = {
        "default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="sqlite:///job.db") 
    }

    SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config())
    scheduler = APScheduler()
    scheduler.init_app(app)
    scheduler.start()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by changing args from "(testing2)" to ["testing"].

{
"id":"testing2",
"func":"app:run",
"args":["testing2"],
"trigger":"interval",
"seconds":5
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed description of the solution? An example of the job definition on the code would be very helpful. I mean, not in JSON format.